Mozilla VPN on Debian over Comcast Xfinity X8B-T modem - no connectivity when connected to VPN server
Mozilla VPN (based on Wireguard) connects to the chosen server, but then I can't reach any website (timeouts). As soon as I disconnect from Mozilla VPN server, connectivity resumes. How to fix it? It does not matter which VPN server I connect to.

The reason is in /etc/resolv.conf. When Comcast is the ISP, resolv.conf contents become:
# Generated by NetworkManager
search hsd1.tx.comcast.net
nameserver 212.14.1.62
nameserver 212.14.1.82
nameserver 75.75.75.75
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 75.75.76.76
nameserver 2001:558:feed::1
nameserver 2001:558:feed::2


For some reason these settings don't work with Mozilla VPN. An entry at the beginning of the file pointing at another DNS server makes VPN work again.

Disconnect from Mozilla VPN server
Edit the file with sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
Insert this line at the beginning: nameserver 8.8.8.8
It's Google's DNS server, haven't tried with others.
Press Ctrl-O to save, then Ctrl-X to exit nano.

Restart your browser, connect to Mozilla VPN. Your connectivity should be fine now. The downside of this method is that it needs to be repeated after every reboot. The neater way would be to tell NetworkManager how to populate resolv.conf, but I had no time to dig deeper.

except if you're using NetworkManager with systemd

please clarify, @admstg
